# mod_rewrite causes loss of stylesheet

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to clean up some of my URL's (duh) and I got it working. Sorta. It redirects to the correct page, but the stylesheet doesn't show up. Here's my code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ post.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So what's going on? This is my first time working with mod_rewrite, by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be your CSS link is broken by your new URLs if you are using relative links. e.g:

Stylesheet link used:  `../css/stylesheet.css`
Old page: `/blog/example/post.php`
New page: `/blog/2009/12/example/post.php`

This break would affect images too.
An easy way to fix this is to decide upon the definitive URL for the CSS and absolute link it. e.g.

```
/css/stylesheet.css
```

This would mean that irregardless of where you are in the structure, the CSS (or images, if you follow this routine) would show up ok.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS (Lets Assume /blog/style.css) is going to post.php?page=style.css

To Fix, I'd suggest putting this right after the RewriteEngine

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
```

That will forward all requests where the file exists, like a CSS/JS file, directly to the file.

In the future, I suggest browsing to the URL on a browser, and see where it leads you to. If it doesn't work in the browser, it won't work for the page.

Comment: Ok, right now the stylesheet is inits own directory at /style/stylesheet.css Does that change anything? I did what you said above and it gave me a 404 error. Also, I don't see why it doesn't work because when I go to the URL that its REALLY going to, it works perfectly. Isn't it basically just doing a redirect, and there fore just like going to the ACTUAL page? Confused...

Comment: If you browse to some.thing.com/style/stylesheet.css, do you get it? If so, your HTML page should have the same URL you browse to to get it as the CSS page in your <link> tag.

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably just your new URLs that cause that relative URLs are resolved differently than with your old URLs. Try it with an absolute URL path like this:

```
/style/screen.css
```

Instead of a relative URL path like:

```
style/screen.css
./style/screen.css
```